# Why does dragging over a select list change or clear the selection?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, html-select

In Chrome and Safari, if I drag from outside a `<select>` list that has a `size` attribute (i.e. it's rendered as a list, not a drop-down), the selected option changes or the selection disappears altogether. Live example:

```html
<p>Click anywhere outside the list below and drag over the list. Observe that the selected option becomes deselected.</p>
<select size="4">
  <option selected="">option</option>
  <option>option</option>
  <option>option</option>
</select>
```

Observed in Chrome 39 on Windows 7 and OS X Yosemite (EDIT: still present in Chrome 43 on Yosemite at least), and Safari 8 on Yosemite. Internet Explorer 11 doesn't exhibit the same behaviour.

If you're not paying attention, and select some text in an input for example, it's quite easy to overrun with your mouse and accidentally change the selection without even realizing.

Is there any good reason for this behaviour? Is there a way (e.g. through CSS/javascript) of stopping it from happening? I've tried dragenter/dragover event handling but they don't fire unless something is actually being dragged, whereas this behaviour happens even when you "drag" empty space over the list.

Comment: It's clearly bug in their implementation. You can create bug in blink bugzilla.

Comment: And webkit's I guess. Hooray for fragmentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so this may be a bug (and should be reported), but the fix is quite simple. Just `preventDefault()` for the `onmousemove` event of the select element.

My guess is that the bug has something to do with some drag related code.

Demo:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('myselect');
elem.onmousemove = function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
};
```

```html
<p>Click anywhere outside the list below and drag over the list. Observe that the selected option becomes deselected.</p>
<select id="myselect" size="4">
  <option selected="">option</option>
  <option>option</option>
  <option>option</option>
</select>
```

Hope this helps :)